# Asgardcms - Undefined variable: media when creating a new blog post

Tags: php, laravel, docker, asgardcms

I created a cms with asgardcms framework already but now I would like to deploy my project using docker. It seems the website work normally but when I want to insert a new record through the cms, it shows an error message "compact(): Undefined variable: media (View: ....)".

It seems the cause of the problem is because of a line of code `@mediaSingle('cover_img')`. When I removed this line of code, the error message did not pop up.

I doubted if the version of the packages installed are different so I have tried building my project without using docker and run `php composer update` to test it. But it worked well.
How to fix this problem? Thank you!

My create-fields.blade.php

```
<div class="box-body">
    <select class="selectpicker" style="width:100%;" name="title_color">
        <option value="0c15c0" data-icon="color1" >#0c15c0</option>     
    </select>
    <br>
    @mediaSingle('cover_img')
    <p>Cover Image Size (320px x 215px)</p>
    {!! Form::normalTextarea('title', 'Title', $errors) !!}
    {!! Form::normalTextarea('content', 'Content', $errors) !!}

    <div class="form-group ">
        <label>Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" required="required">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dicovered asgardcms few days ago and few hours ago I run into same problem after installing blog module. Now it's very disapointing seeing same error from years ago. Anyway I quickly figured out the problem. When you look into Modules/Media/Blade/MediaSingleDirective.php:39 seems to be setting $media variable only under condition which is clearly wrong implementation of a variable which is used anyways and being defined only when condition applies.Add ``$media=null;`` just before line 38 where it says ``if ($this->entity !== null) `` and whala, it works.